# USING CAST STATEMENT IN INSERT INTO STATEMENT SQL

Tags: sql, casting, sql-insert, vertica

Below (1) is the query which I wrote and when I am not using CAST i am getting error (2) and when am using cast its throwing another syntax error(3)

(1)

```
 /*DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LFB1_BACKUPTABLE
 CREATE TABLE LFB1_BACKUPTABLE AS   
(SELECT * FROM LFB1);
*/


INSERT INTO LFB1_BACKUPTABLE (
    MANDT,LIFNR,BUKRS,PERNR,ERDAT,ERNAM,SPERR,LOEVM,ZUAWA,
    AKONT,BEGRU,VZSKZ,ZWELS,XVERR,ZAHLS,ZTERM,EIKTO,ZSABE,
    KVERM,FDGRV,BUSAB,LNRZE,LNRZB,ZINDT,ZINRT,DATLZ,XDEZV,
    WEBTR,KULTG,REPRF,TOGRU,HBKID,XPORE,QSZNR,QSZDT,QSSKZ,
    BLNKZ,MINDK,ALTKN,ZGRUP,MGRUP,UZAWE,QSREC,QSBGR,QLAND,
    XEDIP,FRGRP,TOGRR,TLFXS,INTAD,XLFZB,GUZTE,GRICD,GRIDT,
    XAUSZ,CERDT,CONFS,UPDAT,UPTIM,NODEL,TLFNS,AVSND,AD_HASH,
    J_SC_SUBCONTYPE,J_SC_COMPDATE,J_SC_OFFSM,J_SC_OFFSR,
    BASIS_PNT,GMVKZK,PREPAY_RELEVANT,ASSIGN_TEST, CAST(_CELONIS_CHANGE_DATE AS DATE) AS _CELONIS_CHANGE_DATE 
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM LFB1
WHERE MANDT||LIFNR||BUKRS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MANDT||LIFNR||BUKRS FROM 
LFB1_BACKUPTABLE);
```

(2) Execution error:

> [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Column "_CELONIS_CHANGE_DATE" is of type timestamptz but expression is of type varchar

(3) Execution error:

> [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Syntax error at or near "CAST"

Comment: The insert column list may only contain column names. I.e. do something like `INSERT INTO t1 (col1, col2, col3) select colx, coly, cast(d as date) from t2`

Comment: `WHERE MANDT||LIFNR||BUKRS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MANDT||LIFNR||BUKRS ` is a really bad idea. You should use `WHERE (MANDT, LIFNR, BUKRS) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MANDT, LIFNR, BUKRS  ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a cast statement in your insert table column list? You can't change the type of the destination table columns.

You need to change the type of the values you are inserting.

```
INSERT INTO LFB1_BACKUPTABLE (
        MANDT,LIFNR,BUKRS,PERNR,ERDAT,ERNAM,SPERR,LOEVM,ZUAWA,
        AKONT,BEGRU,VZSKZ,ZWELS,XVERR,ZAHLS,ZTERM,EIKTO,ZSABE,
        KVERM,FDGRV,BUSAB,LNRZE,LNRZB,ZINDT,ZINRT,DATLZ,XDEZV,
        WEBTR,KULTG,REPRF,TOGRU,HBKID,XPORE,QSZNR,QSZDT,QSSKZ,
        BLNKZ,MINDK,ALTKN,ZGRUP,MGRUP,UZAWE,QSREC,QSBGR,QLAND,
        XEDIP,FRGRP,TOGRR,TLFXS,INTAD,XLFZB,GUZTE,GRICD,GRIDT,
        XAUSZ,CERDT,CONFS,UPDAT,UPTIM,NODEL,TLFNS,AVSND,AD_HASH,
        J_SC_SUBCONTYPE,J_SC_COMPDATE,J_SC_OFFSM,J_SC_OFFSR,
        BASIS_PNT,GMVKZK,PREPAY_RELEVANT,ASSIGN_TEST, _CELONIS_CHANGE_DATE
)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, ..., timestamp_col::DATE FROM LFB1
WHERE MANDT||LIFNR||BUKRS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MANDT||LIFNR||BUKRS FROM LFB1_BACKUPTABLE);
```

Your syntax for casting to a date is syntactically correct, but in this example I used the more common Vertica syntax which is `col::DATE`, both will work.